# Excel: Range of cells, first cell in column to second to last cell in the same column

Tags: excel

My formula looks like the following:
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A8="o"),--(A2:A="f"))

I want the first range (A1:A8) to start at A1 and go to the second to last cell in my column (A8) without having to type the row number (8). Each cell has a letter.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yed3e.png)

Comment: Can you include a screenshot or a little more detail of what's not doing what you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out something that works, though someone may have a prettier way of doing it.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(OFFSET(A:A,,,ROWS(A:A)-1,1)="o"),--(A2:A="f"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `A2:A` is not Excel syntax and should not work. Rework your question and answer to show you are (probably) using Google Sheets.